# Explanation and Pronunciation of Superscript Hash

Tags: notation

I wanted to know how to pronounce the superscript # symbol in the following sentence and whether it has a specific meaning when applied to T:

"With these labels, each motion $ T: X \rightarrow X $ of the square sends each vertex to a vertex, so determines a permutation $ ^\#  T: Y \rightarrow Y $ of the set Y of vertices."

It's from Mathematics Form & Function Chapter 1 part 7. (page 21 in my copy).

Comment: Is it really on the left?  Then “sharp t” I guess.

Comment: @Randall Yes, it is on the left and superscript, & is repeated in the same position multiple times afterwards so wouldn't seem to be a mistake.  Would you always default to 'sharp' for the # symbol when reading mathematical notation?

Comment: In my area, yes, but that’s the limit of my knowledge.

Comment: @Randall do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?